Code output repeats the else section of this if else section
Soo, whenever I run this code, it only repeats the last section on the if else block. It only outputs that one printf repeatedly.
I did use the sscanf thing to check if I can and to prevent buffer overflow.
Code is below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void anongArawNgayon()
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    char* anongAraw = ctime(&now);
    printf("%s", anongAraw);
}

int scanner(const char *data, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char format[30];
    if (buflen == 0)
        return 0;
    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds", (int)(buflen-1));
    return sscanf(data, format, buffer);
}

int main()
{
    char input[30];
    bool tuloyLang = true;

    anongArawNgayon();
    while (tuloyLang)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("di makapagdrive si papa, tuloy ba bukas?\n");
        sscanf("%29s", input, sizeof(input));

        if(strcmp(input, "tuloy")==0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i=15; i++)
            {
                printf("Okay magbihis na kayo\n");
            }
            printf("pero si adriaan ang magdridrive");
        }
        else if(strcmp(input, "hindi")==0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i=15; i++)
            {
                printf("Patay ah");
            }
            printf("commute na lang");
        }
        else if(strcmp(input, "sira")==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ano??");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

I do use Sublime Text as compiler in this case. I tried doing it with turbo c and the same. I tried with vsc on my other laptop and the same thing happens.

for (int i=0; i=15; i++) - you assign 15 to i in the there. I assume you meant i<15 - but why do you want the following printf to be repeated 15 times?

Rather than scanf, based on the name you used and the parameters, I believe you were trying to use something like scanf_s (e.g., as described in scanf_s, _scanf_s_l, wscanf_s, _wscanf_s_l | Microsoft Learn) rather than sscanf (which, as described in sscanf, _sscanf_l, swscanf, _swscanf_l | Microsoft Learn, scans a string only, ...

(cont.) so it doesn't work properly at all and, instead, may crash the program as it's writing output to the wrong location).


int main()
{
    char input[30];
    bool tuloyLang = true;

    anongArawNgayon();
    while (tuloyLang)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("di makapagdrive si papa, tuloy ba bukas?\n");
        sscanf("%29s", input, sizeof(input));


At this point, input is an uninitialized array and your usage of sscanf is incorrect. Why would you expect input to contain "tuloy", '"hindi", or "sira"?
You likely want to use scanf or better yet fgets to read input into input, then check the value of input.
        printf("di makapagdrive si papa, tuloy ba bukas?\n");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

The while loop runs continuously because nothing ever changes the value of tuloyLang and your loop never reaches the explicit break.
The for loops your program never reaches are also wrong.
for (int i=0; i=15; i++)

This will never exit because i=15 is never false. You likely want the following for a loop that executes 15 times.
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)

Be sure to always compile with warnings turned on.

FYI, rather than scanf, based on the name of sscanf they used and their parameters, I believe the OP was trying to use something like scanf_s instead (e.g., as described in scanf_s, _scanf_s_l, wscanf_s, _wscanf_s_l | Microsoft Learn).

I don't want to use scanf, are there any other ways? Also yeah I'm not that familiar with scanf_s

Also it still goes through to the end despite whatever I do. Wile it doesnt print it all anymore, it still is like this
(output)
di makapagdrive si papa, tuloy ba bukas?
skdnbfkd
ano??
di makapagdrive si papa, tuloy ba bukas?
tuloy
ano??
di makapagdrive si papa, tuloy ba bukas?
hindi
ano??
di makapagdrive si papa, tuloy ba bukas?
sira
ano??

I would strongly suggest you think about the practicality of being unwilling to learn new things.

@francis245 If you don't want to use scanf — and that's a good instinct, because it's generally a horrible function — see What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?

I used fgets here. Thanks!

In the middle part of the for statement you assign 15 to i, which happens to be != 0, and after that, each time you evaluate the for condition to execute the block, you will ignore that you have incremented i because you assign 15 again and, will enter again the loop becaue i = 15 is always true.  So you execute the body of for forever, with a value of i equal to 15.
            for (int i=0; i=15; i++)

In case your intention was to repeat a loop with i ranging from 0 to 15 (both included), you should have written something like:
            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)

or, if you want to exclude last value:
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)

(This last being a common C idiom)
